# I2C - What Is a Dummy Read

Tags: c, embedded, i2c

As stated in the title, my question is: what is a "dummy read" in the i2c protocol?

I'm writing a piece of code to control an SH1106 OLED display. The [datasheet](http://www.allshore.com/pdf/SH1106.pdf) explains how to read the RAM of the display controller in this paragraph (page 29):

> 24. Read Display Data
>       Reads 8-bit data from display RAM area specified by column address and page 
>       address. As the column address is increment by 1 automatically after each write, 
>       the microprocessor can continue to read data of multiple words. **A single dummy 
>       read is required immediately after column address being setup** [bold mine]. Refer to the 
>       display RAM section of FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION for details. Note that no display 
>       data can be read via the serial interface.

What does the sentence in bold mean?

Comment: Check the timing dioagrams. It's a normal read, but you discard the data. It is used internally to read the first data entry from emory. This is due to internal pipelining of the device. **Notice the last sentence**: as you seem to use the I2C interface, this section is irrelevant to you. It applies to the paralle interface variant. You **cannot** read the data via I2C or SPI. If you really need the data, hold a copy of the display contents in the MCU RAM (even if a read would be possible, this is prefered because it's magintides faster and massively simplifies the software anyway).

Answer (score 1):

This read is not a true read of the I2C bus, but is a read of the IICD register in the IIC block. It will not be seen on the bus or in any I2C specification because it is internal to the design of the I2C hardware block.

The I2C hardware block includes a state machine that will perform an IIC byte transfer on the bus each time the IICD register is written to or read. The first byte (I2C device address) is sent out when the I2C address value is written to the IICD register. Once this has been written out then it needs the Dummy Read to initiate the transfer of the next byte. Note that it is a Dummy Read because there is no real data in the IICD register yet because the hardware has not actually done the transfer.